# how can i fix this i want to convert decimal number to binary

Tags: java

```
public class Binar{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num = 7;
    long Binary = cBtD(num);
System.out.printf("%d numri decimal = %d binar" , num, Binary);
}
public static long cBtD(int num){
    long BinaryNumber = 0;
    int  i = 0;
    long reminder;
    while(num > 0){
        reminder = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
        ++i;
    }
  for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(BinaryNumber[j]); 
  }
    return BinaryNumber;
}}
```

and i have this error and it says "array required, but long found" and "System.out.print(BinaryNumber[j]);"

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind this error is, you have defined `BinaryNumber` variable as `long` and it is not an array. But you are trying to access it like an array. Please check my modified answer below:

```
public class Binar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 7;
    String Binary = cBtD(num);
    System.out.printf("%d numri decimal = %s binar", num, Binary);
}

public static String cBtD(int num) {
    String BinaryNumber = "";
    long reminder;
    if (num == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    while (num > 0) {
        reminder = num % 2;
        BinaryNumber = String.valueOf(reminder).concat(BinaryNumber);
        num /= 2;
    }
    return BinaryNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: You should follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `Binary` should be `binary` and `BinaryNumber` should be `binaryNumber`. Also, when it comes to concatenating strings inside a loop, it is better to use `StringBuilder::append` than direct `String` concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurred because you defined BinaryNumber's type 'long' and you wanted use it as an array.

I change it a bit, try it:

```java
public class Binar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 7;
        int[] binaryArray = cBtD(num);
        String numbers = "";
        for (int aBinaryArray : binaryArray)
            numbers += aBinaryArray;

        System.out.printf("%d numri decimal = %d binar" , num, Integer.parseInt(numbers));
    }

    private static int[] cBtD(int num){
        int i = 0;
        int temp[] = new int[7];
        int binaryNumber[];
        while (num > 0) {
            temp[i++] = num % 2;
            num /= 2;
        }
        binaryNumber = new int[i];
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            binaryNumber[k++] = temp[j];
        }
        return binaryNumber;
    }
}
```

Or you can simply use these methods to convert decimal to binary:

```java
Integer.toBinaryString();
```

Or this:

```java
Integer.toString(n,2);
```

Comment: Your welcome! Please vote me up if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers are inherently binary.  But whether you display them in binary or hex or octal is simply a matter of representation.  Which means you want to print them as a string.  Even when you do the following:

```
int v = 123;
System.out.println(v); // v is printed as a decimal string.
```

So to convert them to a binary string, just prepend the remainders to the string after dividing by two (via the remainder operator).

```
int n = 11;
String s = "";

s = (n%2) + s; // s = "1"
n/=2;  // n == 5
s = (n%2) + s; // s = "11"
n/=2   // n == 2
s = (n%2) + s; // s = "011";
n/=2   // n == 1
s = (n%2) + s; // s = "1011";
n/=2;  // n == 0

n == 0 so your done.

return s and print it.
```